# Destructuring within an argument list

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have the following function:

```js
function get_scaled_coordinates(x, y, scale) {
    return [x*scale, y*scale];
}
```

Is it possible if I have a single variable with `[x,y]` to pass to the function. Perhaps something similar to this, conceptually speaking:

```
let point = [1,1];
get_scaled_coordinates(**point, scale);
// instead of having to do get_scaled_coordinates(point[0], point[1], scale)
```

Comment: If you're looking for JavaScript coding style opinions, here's one: camelCase variable names are much more common than snake_case names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take an array as target for destructuring.

```
function get_scaled_coordinates([x, y], scale) {
    return [x * scale, y * scale];
}
```

If you like to use higher dimensions, you could map the array with new values.

```
function get_scaled_coordinates(coordinates, scale) {
    return coordinates.map(v => v * scale);
}
```

Comment: thanks for this. What do you mean by "use higher dimensions?"

Comment: if you have a value for `z`, for example in 3d.

Answer (score 0):

> Perhaps something similar to this, conceptually speaking:
>
> ```
> get_scaled_coordinates(**point, scale);
> ```

You seem to be looking for [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) in the function call:

```
get_scaled_coordinates(...point, scale);
```

No need to change the function, making it accept an array.